# In Perl when using AIO how to serialize file access between different processes?

Tags: perl, asynchronous

The unix based perl program I am working on makes heavy use of Asynchronous IO (Based around Coro, AIO, AnyEvent and EV) to ensure that hardware interaction doesn't degrade performance.  Within a single process I've been using Coro::Semaphore to lock access to the file.

However I now have a use case where potentially two instances of my program will be running as different processes on the same computer will be modifying this file.

The program often writes to this file so I'm looking for a way that works within the Asynchronous IO framework that I've outlined above that doesn't degrade performance or cause my program to have to wait on IO.

Comment: Create a lock file, try to get an exclusive lock on it, otherwise wait for it to be available...
http://perl.plover.com/yak/flock/

Comment: If I was solving this problem using synchronous IO that would be where I would go.  But I don't see an async command to get an exclusive lock on a file.